# What does the termination (number).(number)[a](number)[d0] means in an output(printf) in java?

Tags: java, output

I have a problem. When I save a *.txt of the output of a program i get this:
0.021111111111111112a118d0 and many more things.

The question is:

What does the "d0" and "a" means in this number?
I don't know if "d0" has something to do with the format (double or decimal), and "a" with something like an exponent or another thing.
I was searching on the web but nothing. Anything that you could tell me about it i'll thank you for it.
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of the program and how are you writing it to the `txt` file?

Comment: I really think we need more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you talk about the [Hexadecimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) , which have the base `16` (from 0 to 9 , then  a(10) , b(11) , c(12) , d(13) , e(14) and  f(15))

and i think `d0` is d-->(13) and 0-->(0)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%a, or in capitals %A", 0x1.5p3, 0x1p3);
```

Hexadecimal floating point literals look like `0x(mantissa)p(exponent)`.
In [formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) `%a` is used.